# Finding the distance between a point and a parabola with different methods

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to find the shortest distance from point $(3,0)$ to the parabola $y= x^2$ using the method of Lagrange Multipliers (my practice), and by "reducing to unstrained problem in one variable" (assignment). (I think the sheet might have meant unrestrained, but in either case, I don't know how to go about it).

How would I go about this?

For Lagrange Multipliers, I think the set-up (from what I've read) is something like $(x-3, y) = λ(2x, ??)$ But I'm unsure where to get the y coordinate for the lambda side. I then solve for λ. From there on, I have no idea what to do.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or walk me through this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For Lagrange, minimize $(x-3)^2+y^2$ subject to $y-x^2=0$. So we look at $(x-3)^2+y^2 -\lambda(y-x^2)$. For one variable, plug in $x^2$ for $y$ in $(x-3)^2+y^2$, and minimize the resulting function of $x$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "minimize"? Take the second derivative and find where it equals zero and determine if it's a minimum?

Comment: Take the first derivative, set it equal to $0$. Because of the geometry we need to worry also about $x=0$.

Comment: For Lagrange, taking the first partial derivative of both I assume? Then what?

Comment: Set equal to $0$, solve together with $y=x^2$.

Comment: So I'm taking the partial derivatives for x and y of $(x-3)^2 + y^2 - λ(y-x^2)$ and then setting those equal to zero respectively, to find a point $(x,y)$? Where does λ come into play?

Comment: The partial derivatives will involve $\lambda$. Alternately, set the partials with respect to $x$, $y$, and $\lambda$ equal to $0$.

Comment: After a while, either way, we get a cubic in $x$. By good luck (!) the cubic has the obvious solution $x=1$, and no other real solutions.

Comment: Could you work it out in an answer? I'm not following exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Which version, the one variable substitution or the Lagrange multiplier version? Particularly for the second, it is useful to make an appeal to the geometry to argue we really have obtained the minimum.

Comment: I would say both. For Lagrange I'm just not certain of my work, and for the second one the wording confuses me, and I'm still not sure what I need to do. At your discretion of course. I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: By the way, the word should be *unconstrained*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture.

For either method, we want to minimize $(x-3)^2+y^2$, subject to $y=x^2$.

Substituting $x^2$ for $y$ in $(x-3)^2+y^2$, we find that we want to minimize $f(x)=(x-3)^2+x^4$. Note that $f'(x)=2(x-3)+4x^3$. The critical points of $f(x)$ are where $2(x-3)+4x^3=0$, or equivalently
$$2x^3+x-3=0.$$
In general cubic equations are unpleasant to solve. However, the above equation has the obvious root $x=1$. And since $f''(x)=3x^2+1\gt 0$, the function $f'(x)$ is increasing, and therefore can only have one zero. By the geometry, there **is** at least one point on the parabola at minimum distance from $(3,0)$, so we have found it. The minimum distance is the distance from $(3,0)$ to $(1,1)$, which is $\sqrt{5}$.

We now sketch the Lagrange multipliers approach. The Lagrangian is
$$(x-3)^2+y^2-\lambda(y-x^2).$$
Take the partial derivatives, and set them equal to $0$. We get $2(x-3)+2\lambda x=0$ and $2y-\lambda=0$.

So $\lambda=2y$. Substituting in the first equation we get $2(x-3)+4yx=0$. Putting $y=x^2$ we obtain $2(x-3)+4x^3=0$, and we are at an equation we have already dealt with.

Comment: Thank you. That's much clearer now. I think I was getting lost on the substitution. Just wasn't clicking for me. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. You persisted, persistence is good.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but with $r$ in place of $3$. The cubic equation is driving me insane.